# Angular - Data loader - async binding or normal

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs

I would like to add a universal loader (spinner or something like this) in Angular 7 application. When I go to the specific route (page), firstly I get data from the server. During request, the loader should be visible.

A first simple solution is a service like here:

```js
class PendingService {
    active = 0;
    isActive = false;

    start() {
        this.active++;
        this.isActive = true;
    }

    stop() {
        this.active--;

        if (this.active === 0) {
            this.isActive = false;
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```js
pendingService.start();
data.get().subscribe(null, null, () => pendingService.stop());
```

with binding:

```html
<spinner [hidden]="!pendingService.isActive"></spinner>
```

Second is using rjxs and use where pending will be observable boolean.

```html
<spinner [hidden]="pendingService.pending | async"></spinner>
```

What solution will be more proper and faster for Angular 7?

Answer (score 1):

There's no "proper" way, but `async` pipe has the main advantage that it will automatically unsubscribe from `Observable` when the component is destroyed. You will not need to store subscription into variable and unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy()` hook.

Comment: Not only that, but it allows to change the detection strategy and set it to `onPush` without further modification to your code, resulting in better maintainability, and *in fine*, better performance.

Comment: @trichetriche fully agree!